# background image with text overlay and background color responsive even to 4k screens

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out how I can have a background image and overlay text with it.  That portion is easy.  The issue I am running into is I also want a background color so when the width of the screen is wider than the image I don't want to stretch the image.  I want there to be a background color extending out for 100% width.  The background image color matches the edge of the image color so it looks like the image just keep extending.  To do this I have something like the jsfiddle listed below.

The issues I am running into is ideally I want the text to line up with where the image is and not over the background color but that changes as screensize changes.  Also when the screen gets smaller such as tablet and mobile phone I would want the image to shrink accordingly but then the background color would start showing under the image as well if I set it to a height.

https://jsfiddle.net/j1ktafd8/5/

```
<div class="container py-5">
        <div class="row justify-content-center" style="">
        <div class="overlay">


          This is the text.
          <p>
          Some more text.
          </div>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

.row {
  background: #34ca69 url('//via.placeholder.com/500') no-repeat center;
  height: 500px;
  color: grey;
  width: 100%;
}

.overlay {
  padding-left: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Is this what you want to achieve or did you mean something else? https://jsfiddle.net/kn37ev0w/

Comment: Have you tried adding background color to the <body>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this. I would probably go for a solution like this:

1. Since you want the background color to have the same height as the background image element, the element with the background color needs to get its height from the background image element. That means, the background image element should be inside the element with the background color.
2. The background image element is a 100% wide, but has a `max-width`. That way to image never becomes to big and shrinks on smaller screens.
3. You need to use the padding-bottom trick to set the height of the background image element. You could avoid that by using an image element, but that's a question of semantics.

https://jsfiddle.net/tvfr42ys/

Comment: I think this will do it.  I am going to try to implement with my code and then hopefully marked as correct.  Thanks